# Play 2.x Json transform json keys to camelCase from underscore case

Tags: json, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I want to transform a json with underscore case keys to camel case keys.

```
"{\"first_key\": \"first_value\", \"second_key\": {\"second_first_key\":\"second_first_value\"}}"
```

to

```
 "{\"firstKey\": \"first_value\", \"secondKey\": {\"secondFirstKey\":\"second_first_value\"}}"
```

This is partial code:

```
val CamelCaseRegex = new Regex("(_.)")
val jsonTransformer = (__).json.update(
  //converts json camel_case field names to Scala camelCase field names  
)
val jsonRet = Json.parse(jsonStr).transform(jsonTransformer)
```

I have tried several ways in the update method without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it would be nice to do this with just the native Play library, it's a good use-case for Mandubian's [Play Json Zipper](https://github.com/mandubian/play-json-zipper) extension libraries.

Here's a quick go at this (not exhaustively tested). First you need to add the resolver and library to your build:

```
resolvers += "mandubian maven bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/mandubian/maven"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.mandubian"     %% "play-json-zipper"    % "1.2"
)
```

Then you could try something like this:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.extensions._

// conversion function borrowed from here:
// https://gist.github.com/sidharthkuruvila/3154845
def underscoreToCamel(name: String) = "_([a-z\\d])".r.replaceAllIn(name, {m =>
  m.group(1).toUpperCase
})

// Update the key, otherwise ignore them...
// FIXME: The None case shouldn't happen here so maybe we
// don't need it...
def underscoreToCamelCaseJs(json: JsValue) = json.updateAllKeyNodes {
  case (path, js) => JsPathExtension.hasKey(path) match {
    case Some(key) => underscoreToCamel(key) -> js
    case None => path.toJsonString -> js
  }
}
```

Which on this input:

```
val testJson = Json.obj(
  "some_str" -> JsString("foo_bar"),
  "some_obj" -> Json.obj(
    "some_field" -> Json.arr("foo", "bar")
  ),
  "an_int" -> JsNumber(1)
)
```

...produces:

```
{
  "someStr" : "foo_bar",
  "someObj" : {
    "someField" : [ "foo", "bar" ]
  },
  "anInt" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement, you can use this library **play-json-naming**. It easily converts `snake_case`(underscore case) json to `camelCase` and vice versa.
https://github.com/tototoshi/play-json-naming

Answer (score 0):

If you're using play >= 2.6:

```
final case class Blah(foo: String)

object Blah {
  import play.api.libs.json._

  implicit val config = JsonConfiguration(SnakeCase)

  implicit val blahReader:OFormat[QueueMsgEnvelope] = Json.format[Blah]
}
```

- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonAutomated#Custom-Naming-Strategies